# ajaxFileUpload Syntax Error after upload on server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using ajaxFileUpload jquery plugin in my codeigniter script for ajax upload!

However, I don't know if it's a browser dependent error.
I develop locally (localhost) and the script works perfect, however, when I use the script on a live site with exactly the same software (PHP - self developed) I get this error `"SyntaxError: syntax error eval( "data = " + data );"`

Is it possible that it could be because of a delay in the post that could cause this...?

please help!!!

ajaxFileUpload.js code:

```
jQuery.extend({


    createUploadIframe: function(id, uri)
    {
            //create frame
            var frameId = 'jUploadFrame' + id;
            var iframeHtml = '<iframe id="' + frameId + '" name="' + frameId + '" style="position:absolute; top:-9999px; left:-9999px"';
            if(window.ActiveXObject)
            {
                if(typeof uri== 'boolean'){
                    iframeHtml += ' src="' + 'javascript:false' + '"';

                }
                else if(typeof uri== 'string'){
                    iframeHtml += ' src="' + uri + '"';

                }   
            }
            iframeHtml += ' />';
            jQuery(iframeHtml).appendTo(document.body);

            return jQuery('#' + frameId).get(0);            
    },
    createUploadForm: function(id, fileElementId, data)
    {
        //create form   
        var formId = 'jUploadForm' + id;
        var fileId = 'jUploadFile' + id;
        var form = jQuery('<form  action="" method="POST" name="' + formId + '" id="' + formId + '" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>');    
        if(data)
        {
            for(var i in data)
            {
                jQuery('<input type="hidden" name="' + i + '" value="' + data[i] + '" />').appendTo(form);
            }           
        }       
        var oldElement = jQuery('#' + fileElementId);
        var newElement = jQuery(oldElement).clone();
        jQuery(oldElement).attr('id', fileId);
        jQuery(oldElement).before(newElement);
        jQuery(oldElement).appendTo(form);



        //set attributes
        jQuery(form).css('position', 'absolute');
        jQuery(form).css('top', '-1200px');
        jQuery(form).css('left', '-1200px');
        jQuery(form).appendTo('body');      
        return form;
    },

    ajaxFileUpload: function(s) {
        // TODO introduce global settings, allowing the client to modify them for all requests, not only timeout        
        s = jQuery.extend({}, jQuery.ajaxSettings, s);
        var id = new Date().getTime()        
        var form = jQuery.createUploadForm(id, s.fileElementId, (typeof(s.data)=='undefined'?false:s.data));
        var io = jQuery.createUploadIframe(id, s.secureuri);
        var frameId = 'jUploadFrame' + id;
        var formId = 'jUploadForm' + id;        
        // Watch for a new set of requests
        if ( s.global && ! jQuery.active++ )
        {
            jQuery.event.trigger( "ajaxStart" );
        }            
        var requestDone = false;
        // Create the request object
        var xml = {}   
        if ( s.global )
            jQuery.event.trigger("ajaxSend", [xml, s]);
        // Wait for a response to come back
        var uploadCallback = function(isTimeout)
        {           
            var io = document.getElementById(frameId);
            try 
            {               
                if(io.contentWindow)
                {
                     xml.responseText = io.contentWindow.document.body?io.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML:null;
                     xml.responseXML = io.contentWindow.document.XMLDocument?io.contentWindow.document.XMLDocument:io.contentWindow.document;

                }else if(io.contentDocument)
                {
                     xml.responseText = io.contentDocument.document.body?io.contentDocument.document.body.innerHTML:null;
                    xml.responseXML = io.contentDocument.document.XMLDocument?io.contentDocument.document.XMLDocument:io.contentDocument.document;
                }                       
            }catch(e)
            {
                jQuery.handleError(s, xml, null, e);
            }
            if ( xml || isTimeout == "timeout") 
            {               
                requestDone = true;
                var status;
                try {
                    status = isTimeout != "timeout" ? "success" : "error";
                    // Make sure that the request was successful or notmodified
                    if ( status != "error" )
                    {
                        // process the data (runs the xml through httpData regardless of callback)
                        var data = jQuery.uploadHttpData( xml, s.dataType );    
                        // If a local callback was specified, fire it and pass it the data
                        if ( s.success )
                            s.success( data, status );

                        // Fire the global callback
                        if( s.global )
                            jQuery.event.trigger( "ajaxSuccess", [xml, s] );
                    } else
                        jQuery.handleError(s, xml, status);
                } catch(e) 
                {
                    status = "error";
                    jQuery.handleError(s, xml, status, e);
                }

                // The request was completed
                if( s.global )
                    jQuery.event.trigger( "ajaxComplete", [xml, s] );

                // Handle the global AJAX counter
                if ( s.global && ! --jQuery.active )
                    jQuery.event.trigger( "ajaxStop" );

                // Process result
                if ( s.complete )
                    s.complete(xml, status);

                jQuery(io).unbind()

                setTimeout(function()
                                    {   try 
                                        {
                                            jQuery(io).remove();
                                            jQuery(form).remove();  

                                        } catch(e) 
                                        {
                                            jQuery.handleError(s, xml, null, e);
                                        }                                   

                                    }, 100)

                xml = null

            }
        }
        // Timeout checker
        if ( s.timeout > 0 ) 
        {
            setTimeout(function(){
                // Check to see if the request is still happening
                if( !requestDone ) uploadCallback( "timeout" );
            }, s.timeout);
        }
        try 
        {

            var form = jQuery('#' + formId);
            jQuery(form).attr('action', s.url);
            jQuery(form).attr('method', 'POST');
            jQuery(form).attr('target', frameId);
            if(form.encoding)
            {
                jQuery(form).attr('encoding', 'multipart/form-data');               
            }
            else
            {   
                jQuery(form).attr('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');            
            }           
            jQuery(form).submit();

        } catch(e) 
        {           
            jQuery.handleError(s, xml, null, e);
        }

        jQuery('#' + frameId).load(uploadCallback   );
        return {abort: function () {}}; 

    },

    uploadHttpData: function( r, type ) {
        var data = !type;
        data = type == "xml" || data ? r.responseXML : r.responseText;
        // If the type is "script", eval it in global context
        if ( type == "script" )
            jQuery.globalEval( data );
        // Get the JavaScript object, if JSON is used.
        if ( type == "json" )
            eval( "data = " + data );
        // evaluate scripts within html
        if ( type == "html" )
            jQuery("<div>").html(data).evalScripts();

        return data;
    }
})
```

My Controler code:

```
<?php 
class Upload extends CI_Controller
{
   public function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();
      //$this->load->model('files_model');
      //$this->load->database();
      $this->load->helper('url');
   }

   public function index()
   {
      $this->load->view('upload');
   }

   public function upload_file()
{
   $status = "";
   $msg = "";
   $file_element_name = 'userfile';

   if (empty($_POST['title']))
   {
      $status = "error";
      $msg = "Please enter a title";
   }

   if ($status != "error")
   {
      $config['upload_path'] = './files/';
      $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|txt';
      $config['max_size']  = 1024 * 8;
      $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

      $this->load->library('upload', $config);

      if (!$this->upload->do_upload($file_element_name))
      {
         $status = 'error';
         $msg = $this->upload->display_errors('', '');
      }
      else
      {
         $data = $this->upload->data();
         //$file_id = $this->files_model->insert_file($data['file_name'], $_POST['title']);
         if(true)
         {
            $status = "success";
            $msg = "File successfully uploaded";
         }
         else
         {
            unlink($data['full_path']);
            $status = "error";
            $msg = "Something went wrong when saving the file, please try again.";
         }
      }
      @unlink($_FILES[$file_element_name]);
   }
   echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'msg' => $msg));
}
}
```

My js script code:

```
$(function() {
   $('#upload_file').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajaxFileUpload({
         url         :'./upload/upload_file/',
         secureuri      :false,
         fileElementId  :'userfile',
         dataType    : 'json',
         data        : {
            'title'           : $('#title').val()
         },
         success  : function (data, status)
         {
            if(data.status != 'error')
            {
               //$('#files').html('<p>Reloading files...</p>');
               //refresh_files();
               $('#title').val('');
            }
            alert(data.msg);
         }
      });
      return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: Why not show us your code?

Comment: @Ahmad Here's my codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the PHP script is throwing a Notice or some error that corrupts the JSON output. Check the response data returned by the server, may be there something wrong.